# SSH to intermediate host

Tags: ssh, hosting

I am having difficulty understanding a SSH tunnelling problem. The problem is as follows:

Local Machine --> Intermediate Server --> MySQL Server

The MySQL server can only be accessed from the intermediate server. I have an SSH account for the intermediate server.

How can I connect to the MySQL server from the local machine, specifically from PHP? I want to be able to treat the MySQL server normally, so that I can use PDO with it.

I have tried:

1. Opening ssh (shell_exec('ssh -L 3307:intermediate-server:3306 username@intermediate-server') ) Honestly not entirely sure if this is correct.
2. Connecting using mysqli on port 3307 (to see if a connection can be made).

It doesn't work, I have tried literally everything I can think of.

Comment: Doesn't work how?  What errors.  Do you see anything on the server logs?  Do you see anything if you tcpdump on the intermediate box?    This should work fine.  Though keep in mind that mysql does some weird things if you specify 'localhost' in the client config instead of an IP address.  If localhost is used it switches to using a unix socket instead of IP.

Comment: $output = shell_exec('ssh -L 3307:intermediate-server:3306 username@intermediate-server'); 
$db = mysqli_connect('mysql-host', $env['dbuser'], $env['dbpassword'], $env['dbname'], 3307);` It simply refuses to connect, and eventually times out.

Comment: What the heck are you doing?  Why would you be initiating the SSH connection with a shell_exec?  Your **shell_exec would not even return until the ssh connection has been closed**.  A that point you wouldn't be able to used the tunnel, because it is closed.

Comment: This seems to describe what I want to achieve: http://superuser.com/questions/548462/mysql-access-database-through-remote-machine-without-user-access but it must be entirely in PHP if possible.

Comment: If you really must do everything within PHP, then you should probably be looking to see if your server supports the PHP SSH2 module.  http://php.net/manual/en/book.ssh2.php  Then use that to initiate your connection.

Comment: @Zoredache shell_exec not returning seems to be the problem... Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Your ssh port mapping is incorrect.

The syntax is:

```
<port for ssh server to listen on>:<host to forward to>:<port to forward to>
```

You're using:

```
ssh -L 3307:intermediate-server:3306 username@intermediate-server
```

You should be using:

```
ssh -L 3307:mysql-server:3306 username@intermediate-server
```

In other words, intermediate server should:

- listen on port 3307
- forward to host mysql-server
- on port 3306

Secondly, you don't want to initiate the ssh tunnel from within PHP. You want to do that separately in another process so that it's always on. Either that, or inside PHP check to see if the tunnel is down, and if so fork off and disown an ssh connection.

Answer (score 2):

Use this cure ~/.ssh/config:

```
Host external-server
    User                        root
    Hostname                    1.2.3.4
Host internal-server
    User                        root
    Hostname                    1.2.3.5
    ProxyCommand                ssh external-server nc -q0 %h %p
```

Now you can just

```
$ ssh internal-server
```

Article: http://sshmenu.sourceforge.net/articles/transparent-mulithop.html